# How do I add html tags after the last element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

This is how my html look likes :

```
<div class ="categorie">
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="174" >sdfasdf</input><br>
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="175" >bnmbn</input><br>
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="176" >bnmbn</input><br>
    <div>test</div>
</div>
```

This is the js code that I tried:

```
$(".categorie input:last").append("<input  class='' alt='' value='"+id+"' type='checkbox'>"+category+"</input>");
```

I just want to add  a html code after the last **input** or the last class **checkbox_category**. What am i missing ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should just be

```
$('.categorie').append(...)
```

That appends it to the end after any current content

```js
$(function(){
    $('.categorie').append('<input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="176" >new</input><br>')  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="categorie">
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="174" >sdfasdf</input><br>
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="175" >bnmbn</input><br>
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="176" >bnmbn</input><br>
</div>
```

---

Edit: You can also insert an item before another item using [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/):

```js
$('<input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="176" >new</input><br>').insertBefore('.categorie>div')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="categorie">
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="174" >sdfasdf</input><br>
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="175" >bnmbn</input><br>
    <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="176" >bnmbn</input><br>
    <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will not work if there are non input elements after input element.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar - this will just append whatever to the end - there are already non-input elements (a `<br/>`) and it works just fine

Comment: I just updated my post I forgot to mention that i have an element after the last input

Comment: @JozsefNaghi - do you want the new input before or after the `<div>`?

Comment: I want it before that div

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.next()` to target `br` element along with last input selector and then use **[.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** instead of `.append()` to append content after last inputs next `br` element:

```
 $(".categorie input:last").next().after("<input  class='' alt='' value='"+id+"' type='checkbox'>"+category+"</input><br/>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k9xj4xk1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) like below:

```
$( "<input  class='' alt='' value='"+id+"' type='checkbox'>"+category+"</input>" ).appendTo( ".categorie" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
HTML

```
<div class ="categorie">
  <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="174" />
  <label>Check Box 01</label>
  <br />
  <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="175" />
  <label>Check Box 02</label>
  <br />
  <input class="checkbox_category" type="checkbox" value="176" />
  <label>Check Box 03</label>
  <br />
  <div>test div</div>
</div>

<button id="ad" onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

JS

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function add(){
        var id = "177", category = " Check Box 04",
        input = "<input  class='checkbox_category' value='" + id + "' type='checkbox' />",
        label = "<label>" + category + "</label>",
        br = "<br />",
        html = input + label + br;
        $(".categorie br:last").after(html);
    }
</script>
```

FYI: `<input>` tag has no closing tag `</input>`. Using that will remove from the browser by itself when it gets rendered. If you can check the DOM you can see it. So use a `<label>` tag to place your text.